# How to fix result of command efibootmgr -t 0

Tags: boot

I've entered the efibootmgr -t 0 command accidentally, and now can't boot my OS. Any advice will help.

Comment: Can u access the Grub ?

Answer (score 0):

Here u can get the solution for your issue

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu
```

Change it too

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 5 -B
```

You have used 0 , Instead of 0 if u use 5 it will boot into GUI User mode

Comment: ok Here after ill do it and i don't know About that ...